# How to test if ConsoleKeyInfo is a key that produces a character

Tags: vb.net, console, key

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this but I haven't managed to find anything. I'm trying to write code in VB.NET that will input a key as ConsoleKeyInfo, then runs a block of code if the key normally produces a character (A, 5, :, Enter, Tab, ¬ etc. all count). If the key is something like an arrow key, the winkey, modifier keys, etc., that shouldn't count. Here's the solution I've currently got, which is less than ideal:

```
If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(CKI.KeyChar) Or Char.IsPunctuation(CKI.KeyChar) Or Char.IsWhiteSpace(CKI.KeyChar) Or Char.IsSymbol(CKI.KeyChar) Then
    [Run code]
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the keys, you want to filter out, into a `List(Of ConsoleKey)`.  Then simply see if the `.Key` property of the ConsoleKeyInfo is contained in your list:

```
Dim keylist As List(Of ConsoleKey) = New List(Of ConsoleKey)({ConsoleKey.DownArrow,
                                                                ConsoleKey.UpArrow,
                                                                ConsoleKey.LeftArrow,
                                                                ConsoleKey.RightArrow,
                                                                ConsoleKey.LeftWindows,
                                                                ConsoleKey.RightWindows})
Dim test As ConsoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey
If Not keylist.Contains(test.Key) Then
    'run code
End If
```

There is also an enum for special combination of keys like control-escape

Comment: -1 That's even more tedious than my solution, because it requires me to define every single key I don't want to use, and there could be countless different keyboard keys I couldn't anticipate for, because people may have different keyboards etc.